# Inexplicable connection leak crashes webapp

Tags: java, mysql, spring, c3p0, jdbctemplate

I'm using the Java library C3PO to implement connection pooling with a MySQL database. I'm logging the connections before and after my queries to identify a connection leak. I found one query that uses almost 20 connections when it shouldn't. In fact, when I check the MySQL processlist it creates 50 new processes. *This causes the entire webapp to fail, because the backend can no longer get a connection to the database.*

Here's some pseudo-code for the method that causes the leak.

```
public List<Interaction> getInteractions() {
     // Log the # of connections before the query
     logNumConnections();
     --> stdout: Total (7) Idle: (2) Busy: (5) Orphan: (0)

     // Here's the query that's causing the leak
     String sql="select distinct ... from A left join B on A.x=B.y "
            + "where A.x in (?,?,...)"
     List<Interaction> results = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, args, rowMapper);

     // Log the # connections after the query
     logNumConnections();
     --> stdout: Total (24) Idle: (0) Busy: (24) Orphan: (0)

     return results;
}
```

JdbcTemplate is supposed to close connections and free resources. It shouldn't be using 20 connections for one query! These connections stick around long after the query. Here's the config for my JdbcTemplate and DataSource.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
     <property name="driverClass" value="${database.driver}" />
     <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${database.url}"/>
     <property name="user" value="${database.username}"/>
     <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
     <property name="initialPoolSize" value="5" />
     <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
     <property name="maxPoolSize" value="50" />
     <property name="acquireIncrement" value="1" />
     <property name="maxStatements" value="1000" />
     <property name="maxStatementsPerConnection" value="1000"/>
     <property name="maxIdleTime" value="10000"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
     <constructor-arg>
          <ref bean="dataSource" />
     </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Finally, here is the `explain` statement

```
id|select_type|table|type  |possible_keys|key    |key_len|rows  | Extra  
 1|SIMPLE     |A    |ALL   |NULL         |NULL   |NULL   |437750| Using where; Using temporary
 1|SIMPLE     |B    |eq_ref|PRIMARY      |PRIMARY|4      |1
```

Any idea what could be causing this connection leak?

Comment: The only diff that I have in my config is., am not calling the datasource ref: <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
     <constructor-arg>
          <ref bean="dataSource" />
     </constructor-arg>
</bean> in a constructor, am doing it in the class level and then calling JDBCTemplate the other diff is Initial size of pool was 1 and incremements were in 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the problem. It wasn't the query above that was causing the connection leak. It was a separate AJAX call to a separate method, which was executing in the same time frame as the query above. The query/method above weren't causing any problems after all.

Comment: Did you use  **debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces** with **unreturnedConnectionTimeout**?